# returning error in AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs

I have this authentication service, that checks if the user has a Session stored. and if it get's the info from the api by returning the `$http.post()`:

```
authService.getUser = function () {
    if (!SessionService.get('Auth')) return null;

    $userId = SessionService.get('User');
    SessionService.set('Auth', false); // reset to false

    if ($userId == null) return null;


    return $http.get('/api/users/' + $userId)
        .success(function (res) {
            SessionService.set('Auth', true);
            return res;
        })
        .error(function () {
            return null;
        });
}
```

and this is called like following:

```
AuthenticationService.getUser()
    .success(function (res) {
        $scope.user = res;
        console.log(res);
    })
    .error(function () {
        Materialize.toast('You are not logged in!');
    });
```

but this fails ofcourse when it doesn't have a session stored, because I return null.

So how would you change the service that the `return null` triggers the `error()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply return a rejected promise:

```
return $q.reject();
```

Note that your `.error(...)`is completely useless.

Also note that since you won't return an HTTP promise, but a regular $q promise, the caller shouldn't use `.success()` and `.error()`. It should call `.then()` and `.catch()`.

Comment: yea the error is useless, because I'm still figuring out how to return the rejection so the error is triggerd :) (looking into the $q.reject(); thingy)

Comment: Just remove the .error(). Your service returns the http promise, which will be rejected if the server returns a 4xx or 5xx response, causing the toast to appear.

Comment: ow the error in the $http, yea that one is useless :p but i get a `$q is not defined`

Comment: @Kiwi inject the $q service into your controller